# PIVOT NÃO RETORNA - SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: sql, syntax-error, pivot, sql-server-2016

boa tarde;

Estou tentando alterar algumas colunas em linhas.

Para isso preciso usar o Pivot, porem não esta nem puxando a função.

Segue a consulta que eu faço:

Tabela - SB2010 -- Esta tabela retorna dados de Armazém e Saldo.
SELECT SB2010.B2_LOCAL - Esta Coluna retorna o numero do Armazém.
SB2010.B2_QATU - Esta coluna retorna a Quantidade de Saldo do Armazém.

SELECT SB2010.B2_COD AS Codigo,
[01], [09]
FROM
(
SELECT SB2010.B2_LOCAL, SB2010.B2_QATU
FROM SB2010
) AS NewTable
PIVOT (SUM(SB2010.B2_QATU) FOR SB2010.B2_LOCAL IN ([01], [09])) AS PivotTable

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma sugestão com algumas alterações no código que você postou, basicamente adicionando a coluna Codigo na tabela derivada NewTable e removendo o nome da tabela do primeiro Select e de dentro do Pivot já que a mesma é valida somente dentro da tabela derivada.

```
SELECT Codigo, [01], [09]
FROM
( 
    SELECT SB2010.B2_COD AS Codigo, SB2010.B2_LOCAL, SB2010.B2_QATU 
    FROM SB2010 
) AS NewTable
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(B2_QATU) FOR B2_LOCAL IN ([01], [09])
) AS PivotTable
```